# Separate two words in r

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have data.frame of gene list .

Sample data --

```
gene_name "PPAP2C"
gene_name "PPaw2C"
gene_name "PAP2C"
gene_name "APAP2C"
gene_name "PP102C"
```

I want to separate this data into two column

result data should be -

```
PPAP2C
PPaw2C
PAP2C
APAP2C
PP102C
```

I try to use --

```
xx = x4_1%>% separate(x4_1, c("A","B") , "  "  )
```

error --

> Error: var must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list
>   Call rlang::last_error() to see a backtrace

Comment: can you post `dput(x4_1)` ?

Comment: Sory i cant . because when i try to run dput() it give a log list which is not related to my data .

Comment: if the data is in a data frame. then you select a column using the dplyr::select() function. Alternativly you pull the character vector using the dplyr::pull() function.

Comment: I didn't see anything helpfull using dplyr ::pull() . My data is in single column. Like gene_name "XYZ" and  i want data.frame in result which have only XYZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `separate` approach worked for me:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame("genes" = c("gene_name \"PPAP2C\"",
                   "gene_name \"PPaw2C\"",
                   "gene_name \"PAP2C\"",
                   "gene_name \"APAP2C\"",
                   "gene_name \"PP102C\""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
               genes
1 gene_name "PPAP2C"
2 gene_name "PPaw2C"
3  gene_name "PAP2C"
4 gene_name "APAP2C"
5 gene_name "PP102C"

df <- separate(df, genes, into = c("geneName", "geneCode"), sep = " ")

> df
   geneName geneCode
1 gene_name "PPAP2C"
2 gene_name "PPaw2C"
3 gene_name  "PAP2C"
4 gene_name "APAP2C"
5 gene_name "PP102C"

#Remove any special characters such as quotes:
df$geneCode <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$geneCode)
```

Comment: Okay I will check why its not working with me .

Comment: can you to some modification that will give only name without quotes. as example - in place of "PPAP2C" i want PPAP2C.

Comment: I've made the edit to remove the quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much . separate option did not work with me (not able trace error) but i use --  rd = as.character(x4_1)
s <- strsplit(rd, split = " ")
s2 = plyr::ldply(s, rbind)  and than use gsub ,advice by you . thankyou  sven.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, the help of the function (type `?separate` to access it) specifies what parameters to give and exemples.

```r
library(dplyr)

tt <- c("PPAP2C",
"PPaw2C",
"PAP2C",
"APAP2C",
"PP102C")

tt <- paste0("gene_name", 1:5, " ", tt)
dframe <- tibble("col_to_split" = tt)
dframe %>% tidyr::separate(col = "col_to_split", into = c("col1", "col2"), sep = "\\s")
```

NB : if you deal more with strings (obviously ^^) I suggest looking at the packages `stringr` (manipulation) and `stringi` (encoding) :
http://edrub.in/CheatSheets/cheatSheetStringr.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame("genes" = c("gene_name \"PPAP2C\"",
                             "gene_name \"PPaw2C\"",
                             "gene_name \"PAP2C\"",
                             "gene_name \"APAP2C\"",
                             "gene_name \"PP102C\""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
# genes
# 1 gene_name "PPAP2C"
# 2 gene_name "PPaw2C"
# 3  gene_name "PAP2C"
# 4 gene_name "APAP2C"
# 5 gene_name "PP102C"

df2 <- as.data.frame(str_split(string = df$genes, pattern = ' ', simplify = T))
names(df2) <- c("geneName", "geneCode")
df2$geneCode <- gsub(pattern = '"', replacement = '', x = df2$geneCode)
# geneName geneCode
# 1 gene_name   PPAP2C
# 2 gene_name   PPaw2C
# 3 gene_name    PAP2C
# 4 gene_name   APAP2C
# 5 gene_name   PP102C
```